# Format number only if it's >10000 in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

The title pretty much explains it: 
In google sheets, if the number in the cell is > 10000 - it should be expressed in kilos.

Else, normally.

Example: 
9999 - 9999 
11200 - 11 k 
312400 - 312 k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within sheets, you can try this custom number formatting.

```
[>999]0,"k";[<-999]0,"K";0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to use a formula:

```
=IF(A1>10000, CONCATENATE(INT(A1/1000), " k"), A1)
```

Comment: The cells already have 2 line formulas, adding this on that would complicate things. @rockinfreakshow's answer worked perfectly.